# Wrong Number of Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I understand what causes the wrong number of arguments error but my code doesn't pass any parameters to initialize any of the classes so I'm not sure at all why my code is giving me this error. I'm also pretty new to Ruby on Rails so that doesn't help things. My code is below:

```
def create_google_file  
  @products = Product.find(:all)
  file = File.new('dir.xml','w')
  doc = REXML::Document.new

  root = REXML::Element.new "rss"
  root.add_attribute("xmlns:g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
  root.add_attribute("version", "2.0")

  channel = REXML::Element.new "channel"
  root.add_element channel

  title = REXML::Element.new "title"
  title.text = "Sample Google Base"
  channel.add_element title

  link = REXML::Element.new "link"
  link.text = "http://base.google.com/base/"
  channel.add_element link

  description = REXML::Element.new "description"
  description.text = "Information about products"
  channel.add_element description

  @products.each do |y|
    item = channel.add_element("item")

    id = item.add_element("g:id")
    id.text = y.id

    title = item.add_element("title")
    title.text = y.title

    description = item.add_element("description")
    description.text = y.description

    googlecategory = item.add_element("g:google_product_category")
    googlecategory.text = y.googlecategory

    producttype = item.add_element("g:product_type")
    producttype.text = y.producttype

    link = item.add_element("link")
    link.text = y.link

    imglink = item.add_element("g:image_link")
    imglink.text = y.imglink

    condition = item.add_element("condition")
    condition.text = y.condition

    availability = item.add_element("g:availability")
    availability.text = y.availability

    price = item.add_element("g:price")
    price.text = y.price "USD"

    gtin = item.add_element("g:gtin")
    gtin.text = y.gtin

    brand = item.add_element("g:brand")
    brand.text = y.brand

    mpn = item.add_element("g:mpn")
    mpn.text = y.mpn

    expirationdate = item.add_element("g:expiration_date")
    expirationdate.text = y.salepricedate
  end   

  doc.add_element root

  file.puts doc
  file.close
  end
```

The error I'm getting is:
ArgumentError in ProductsController#create_google_file

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Please post more of your stack trace.

Comment: app/controllers/products_controller.rb:63:in `block in create_google_file'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:32:in `each'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:32:in `create_google_file'

Comment: Where does line 63 correspond to in the code you posted?

Comment: line 63 is price.text = y.price "USD"

Comment: Please stop making us guess where this error is. Dump the stack trace in there and tell us what line numbers we're looking at. Thanks.

Comment: Based purely on the consistency of the other lines, but without knowing which line is actually failing, it may be this part: `price.text = y.price "USD"`. Is `y.price` a method that takes in a parameter? Is it defined as `def price(type)` or something? If not, if it doesn't take any parameters, then it's because you're not supposed to send any parameters to that method. It looks like it's just a getter.

Comment: @FranklinJosephMoormann As I suspected, that's the line. Were you trying to make a string like "4.50 USD"? Then you probably wanted: `price.text = "#{y.price} USD"`. That will take the result of `y.price` and put it in a string, and allow you to keep typing more in the string. It's called string interpolation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am more familiar with string interpolation for other languages and I missed the error that I made there. Please add a reply so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: You're welcome! I've added it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

At the request of the poster, I am putting my comments in to an answer:

Based purely on the consistency of the other lines, but without knowing which line is actually failing, it may be this part: `price.text = y.price "USD"`. Is `y.price` a method that takes in a parameter? Is it defined as `def price(type)` or something? If not, if it doesn't take any parameters, then it's because you're not supposed to send any parameters to that method. It looks like it's just a getter.

@FranklinJosephMoormann As I suspected, that's the line. Were you trying to make a string like "4.50 USD"? Then you probably wanted: `price.text = "#{y.price} USD"`. That will take the result of `y.price` and put it in a string, and allow you to keep typing more in the string. It's called string interpolation.